# Cpu overheating and bios cpu fan error

Tags: cpu, bios, fan, overheating

I have an i5 2550k a p8z68 mobo, and a Corsair h100 liquid cooler.

As of last night the CPU started throttling and I guess overheating after 4 years no issues. Whatever, i tried reapplying new TIM/Thermal paste but motherboard still says 90 Celsius in a matter of minutes.

Oh, and my motherboard started spitting out a "CPU fan error" post code. What should I do now? The CPU didn't even feel hot. The cooler is definitely running and flowing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say the cooler is definitely running and flowing. Do you mean the fans are working on the radiator too? Or can you just feel the slight vibration from the liquid?

Comment: I mean i feel some movement in the tubes, and the fans on the radiator are working fine.

Comment: Are you sure the CPU is overheating? The problem may just be that the fan is not being detected.

Comment: Yes, mobo says 90c.

Comment: Ok issue is fixed. The cooler was the issue. Stock cooler is working fine. How to fix water cooler?

Comment: generally you wouldnt fix a closed water cooler, you would just replace it. did the cooler itself last the full 4 years ?  how many hours a day average?

Comment: Oh gawd. Well i just finally got a life as of last week, so the computer was on about 12 hours A day. Minimum, usually 15 or so.

Comment: By replace, do u mean spend another 100$ on a new h100i? Or replacement tubes or something?

Comment: The water could have gotten nasty, the surfaces even with proper glycol (type) liquids in it could be coated with gunk now. the tubes could be getting stiffer/brittle the motor could be worn, the impeller could be aged and stiff or broken. IMO you replace, or use a premium quality air cooler with much less possible problems.  If you tear it apart, i want to see it in Your Answer that explains that it was the cooler failing . . . please.

Comment: have you tried this?::Enter the BIOS, switch it to Advanced Mode (you can press F7 to switch between EZ mode and Advanced mode), and navigate to the Monitor tab. Once on the Monitor tab, set the CPU Fan Speed from N/A (Not available) to IGNORE. Press F10 to save changes and exit. This will disable the sensor and allow you to boot normally

Answer (score 1):

When you see the error message "CPU FAN Error" in POST, it means the system doesn't detect the FAN.

You can refer to the steps below to resolve the issue.

1. Please make sure the CPU FAN is installed on the right position of the motherboard and twist the screws tightly
2. Ensure that the CPU FAN cable is securely installed to the CPU_FAN connector instead of the CHA_FAN.
3. If you install the other brand of CPU FAN with lower revolutions speed, the system may not able to detect it correctly. You can try to set "CPU Fan Speed Low Limit" to 200 RPM in BIOS configuration.

   - "CPU Fan Speed Low Limit" appears only when you set the CPU Q-Fan Control to [DC Mode], [PWM Mode], and [Auto]. For those early versions, you need to set the CPU Q-Fan Control to [Enabled], [Advance Mode] or [Auto].
4. You can set Monitor->CPU FAN Speed to [Ignore] if you don't want to open the computer case.

*You can set CPU FAN Speed to [Ignore] if your computer coming with water cooling system without fan.

5. Update the BIOS to the latest version.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks, thats from asus´s site i have tried all of that. My cable for the cpu_fan header feels loose or wobbly but that shouldnt matter if its broken. The header isnt at all linked to the cpu temp sensor right?

Comment: If all else fails take it to service.

Comment: The H100i supplied back plate should be snug to the motherboard not loose at all, and if it is loose it is improperly installed and not allowing the clamping pressure is was designed for

Comment: I dont have an h100i. I have an h100.